# how to get the text of an element like this using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

there is a snippets of html codes like this`<label for=name>fill in your name<span>*</span></label>`, when using jquery `$("label[for='name']").text()`, it returned 'fill in your name*',how can get exactly 'fill in your name'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contents()` allows you to select all node types - including just text nodes. For example, this will return the text for the first text node of the element:

```
$("label[for='name']").contents().eq(0).text();
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mX8zK/**

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you don't put the `<span>*</span>` and instead use pseudo-elements (`:after`). That way you can easily get better results.

**[See this EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3b9E2/)**.

Note the cleaner markup:

```
<label for="name" class=required>Fill in your Name</label>
```

Every `.required` label will have the star by default thanks to the `:after` pseudo-element which is applied to it:

```
label.required:after {
    content: '*';
}
```

---

***Important Note:* The mentioned solution will fail on IE7 and below, as they do not support pseudo elements.**